# Sound not working unless starting Pulseaudio from the command line

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio

On my system, audio settings show no available sound card. However, as soon as I start `pulseaudio` from the command line, everything works. Output from `pulseaudio`:

```
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/virtual/sound/timer'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/virtual/sound/seq'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/pcmC0D7p'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/pcmC0D2c'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/pcmC0D3p'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/pcmC0D0p'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/pcmC0D0c'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/hwC0D3'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/hwC0D2'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e47f30 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/controlC0'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e37f40 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_read_db: device 0x1e37f40 filled with db file data
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e39240 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e39570 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e39560 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e39560 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e39560 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e3f270 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_read_db: device 0x1e3f270 filled with db file data
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e40e70 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_read_db: device 0x1e40e70 filled with db file data
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e42290 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_read_db: device 0x1e42290 filled with db file data
libudev: udev_device_new_from_syspath: device 0x1e45a00 has devpath '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0'
libudev: udev_device_read_db: device 0x1e45a00 filled with db file data
```

Output from `lspci`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
```

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS precise, upgraded from Lucid LTS. Worked out of the box on Lucid.

Answer (score 1):

Run 'alsamixer' in termianl and check if master sound is muted.

**oo** is unmute and **mm** is for mute.

---

[image: terminal]

[image: alsamixer]

Answer (score -1):

This is just a guess, but maybe putting pulse audio in your startup applications might solve the issue.